# How to set routes in Express? app.use() vs app.get()

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have site stub, where routing is set in 2 places.

First in `app.js`:

```
...
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
...
```

something is set with `use`. Next inside referred scripts, like `index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var config = require('../config');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var data = {};
    ...
```

Suppose I wish to use infromation from [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) doc. Where I should put the routing for, say, `/users/:userId/books/:bookId`?

In docs, `get` is called against `app`, while in my stub, `get` is called against `router` and in two-step manner.

Where to hook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In docs `get` is called against `app` because they set their endpoints in `app.js` file. In your `index.js` you return the router from the file with `module.exports = router;`, which is app's router. Now in your `app.js` file says

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
```

These are the routes. You are saying that all the endpoints which are in `index` file are starting with `/` and the endpoints which are in `users` file are starting with `/users`.

So the route `/users/:userId/books/:bookId` must be in `users.js` file like this

```
router.get('/:userId/books/:bookId', function(req, res, next) {
   // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handler this route - `/users/:userId/books/:bookId`, then you need to write following handler in your `routes/users.js` file.

```
router.get('/:userId/books/:bookId', function(req, res) {
    var data = {};
});//get route
```

Basically, in app.js you are categorising url's based on its first part e.g. `users`. So, all your routes that start with `/users` will be handled by your `routes/users.js` class. All other routes will be handled by `routes/index.js`, because that is defined to handle `/` (there is no /users, /admin etc. so all routes that are not handled by `users.js` can be handled in this.)

Also, in these route handler files, you define a `router` object, add all route handlers to it and export it at the bottom. So when you are in these files, you need to use `router` and in `app.js` you can directly use `app.get()` etc.